# Angular Ivy: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. However ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule is imported

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, module, angular-reactive-forms

I am currently stumped on how to resolve this issue. As I have discovered from many other posts , the usual fix for this problem is to import **ReactiveFormsModule** and **FormsModule** into *app.module.ts*

I have even included it within the other sub-modules that use reactive forms (**OrganisationFormComponent** and **TeamFormComponent**). However I see the errors shown below within my Visual Studio Code terminal.

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

...twice for seperate components. See :
[Errors In Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p8ZW.png)

I have also tried to replace

> [formGroup]=

to

> formGroup=

but no luck here.

The current errors wont allow my form to submit correctly and therefore not write to the Firebase back end.

The GitHub Repo can be found here for further analysis : https://github.com/joeserve/CRUD-Project

**OrganisationFormComponent**

```
<div>
<h1>{{ !organisationId ? "Create Organisation" : "Edit Organisation" }}</h1>
<form [formGroup]="organisationForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" maxlength="20">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**TeamFormComponent**

```
<div>
<h1>{{ !teamId ? "Create Team" : "Edit Team" }}</h1>
<form [formGroup]="teamForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" maxlength="20">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**OrganisationModule**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OrganisationFormComponent } from './organisation-form/organisation-form.component';
import { OrganisationRoutingModule } from './organisation-routing.module';
import { OrganisationComponent } from './organisation.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [OrganisationComponent,OrganisationFormComponent],
exports: [OrganisationComponent,OrganisationFormComponent],
imports:[
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule ,
    OrganisationRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule],
})
export class OrganisationModule{}
```

**TeamModule**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TeamFormComponent } from './team-form/team-form.component';
import { TeamRoutingModule } from './team-routing.module';
import { TeamComponent } from './team.component';
@NgModule({
declarations: [TeamComponent,TeamFormComponent],
exports: [TeamComponent,TeamFormComponent],
imports:[
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule ,
    TeamRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule],
})
export class TeamModule{}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   FleetComponent,
   UnitComponent,
   AgentComponent,
   HomeComponent,
   TeamComponent,
   StaffComponent,
   LoginComponent,
],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule, 
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   CommonModule,
   RouterModule, 
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
   AngularFirestoreModule,
   AngularFireDatabaseModule,
   appRoutingModule,
 ],
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

    // provider used to create fake backend
    fakeBackendProvider, <-- Not relevant
    OrganisationService,
    TeamService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I apologise for any excessive snippets or info that I present in my question

**Information Update:**

I'm lazy loading in two modules within the app:

*app.routing.ts*

```
 path: 'organisation', loadChildren: () => import('./organisation/organisation-routing.module').then(m => m.OrganisationRoutingModule)
```

*organisation-routing.module.ts*

```
path: ':organisationId/teams', loadChildren: () => import('./team/team-routing.module').then(m => m.TeamRoutingModule)
```

Could this be a source of the problem?

Comment: have you tried to restart the server?

Comment: This looks fine.. should work unless I’m missing something obvious.. just to make sure, did you actually import your feature modules in your app module..? Or are they lazy loaded?

Comment: Updated post reffering to lazy loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're pointing to wrong modules in lazy loaded routes:

**app.routing.ts**

```
{
  path: 'organisation',
  loadChildren: () => import('./organisation/organisation-routing.module')
                              .then(m => m.OrganisationRoutingModule) 
}
```

should be:

```
{
  path: 'organisation',
  loadChildren: () => import('./organisation/organisation.module')
                                   .then(m => m.OrganisationModule)
}
```

**organisation-routing.module.ts**

```
{
  path: ':organisationId/teams',
  loadChildren: () => import('./team/team-routing.module').then(m => m.TeamRoutingModule)
},
```

should be

```
{
  path: ':organisationId/teams',
  loadChildren: () => import('./team/team.module').then(m => m.TeamModule)
},
```